# How does Xcode generate the list of framework directories used in the final linking step?

Tags: xcode, variables, linker, compiler-warnings

**question:**

How does Xcode generate the list of framework directories (-F flags in the call to ld) when building a Cocoa app? I keep getting a warning for an old directory which (I think) I have removed from the project settings.

**details:**

I moved a working Xcode project from one directory to another. I had to fix some broken references to frameworks that now have a different relative path. Everything appears to be working, except for a single warning on the final linker step:

```
ld: warning: directory '../Some/Path/To/Framework' following -F not found
```

`../Some/Path/To/Framework` is definitely part of the old setup. The external frameworks were stored in a directory that was one level up from the project file.

The full text of the call to ld looks something like this (lightly sanitized):

```
Ld /Volumes/Projects/Builds/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp normal i386
cd /Volumes/Projects/MyApp 
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
-L/Volumes/Projects/Builds/Debug -F/Volumes/Projects/Builds/Debug
-F../Some/Path/To/Framework
-F/Correct/Path/To/Framework 
-filelist /Volumes/Projects/Builds/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/
    Objects-normal/i386/MyApp.LinkFileList
-mmacosx-version-min=10.6
-framework Cocoa
-framework FRAMEWORK
-framework Carbon
-framework Quartz
-o /Volumes/Projects/Builds/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
```

The warning is triggered by that old value for `-F`. I have searched through all of the build settings, and everything points to `/Correct/Path/To/Framework`, not `../Some/Path/To/Framework`. I have also cleaned the entire build, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your build settings. The framework search paths are under **Framework Search Paths**, or build variable **FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS**.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I had searched the build settings, but I had different framework search paths for build and debug (not sure why), which meant that the `Framework Search Paths` entry was obscured by a `<multiple values>` label and my search for "../Some/Path..." did not work. Thanks for pointing me to the right spot!